# Issues with WaitForSeconds

Tags: javascript, time, unityscript

I'm learning how to use the *WaitForSeconds* function in Unityscript, and have had success with it before. But now I'm trying it in a script that is supposed to, when the object's health reaches 0, move the object (a box in this case) off-screen, then after a set amount of seconds have it reappear in a random position on-screen, and set the health back to its default value. What I have thus far is:

```
function Update () 
{
    if(health <= 0)
    {
        RespawnWaitTime ();
        var position = Vector3(Random.Range(-6,6),Random.Range(-4.5,4.5),0); //this is the onscreen range   
        transform.position = position;
        health = 2;                 
    }
}

function RespawnWaitTime ()
{
    var offScreen = Vector3(10,10,0);
    transform.position = offScreen;
    yield WaitForSeconds(2);
}
```

However, it doesn't wait the 2 seconds at all. The box just goes straight to its new position as if the function wasn't there. I believe that it does go to its off-screen position, but just jumps straight back without waiting. I've tested to see if it's applying the wait at all by changing some of the code to:

```
function RespawnWaitTime ()
{
    var offScreen = Vector3(10,10,0);
    transform.position = offScreen;
    print("I'm over here!");
    yield WaitForSeconds(2);
    print("I'm coming back!");  
}
```

The first bit of text ends up printing right away, then after two seconds, the second bit of text appears as well, just as expected. So why doesn't the wait apply to the box also? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know unityscript, but let me guess: `WaitForSeconds` takes a callback that is called after said timeout. This is how `setTimeout` in Javascript behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect WaitForSeconds is asynchronously so when update calls RespawnWaitTime then RespawnWaitTime returns immediately. Could you try the following code to see how WaitForSeconds behaves?

```
function Update () {
        print("1 in update before calling respandwaittime");
        RespawnWaitTime ();
        print("3 in update after calling respandwaittime");
}

function RespawnWaitTime (){
    print("2 in in respainwaittime before calling waitforseconds");
    yield WaitForSeconds(2);
    print("4 in in respainwaittime after calling waitforseconds");
}
```

Since the output was 1,2,3,4 (as expected) you could reprogram like so:

```
function Update () {
    if(health <= 0){
        recover();
        return;
    }
}

function recover(){
    var offScreen = Vector3(10,10,0);
    transform.position = offScreen;
    yield WaitForSeconds(2);
    //this is the onscreen range   
    var position = Vector3(Random.Range(-6,6),Random.Range(-4.5,4.5),0); 
    transform.position = position;
    health = 2;                 
}
```

Comment: It printed 1,2,3 immediately upon starting, then after a couple of seconds printed 4. I'm not sure what this would mean for how it behaves though. I'm rather new to coding.

Comment: It doesn't seem as though I can yield during the Update function. "Update() can not be a coroutine" is what the error is telling me.

Comment: I had actually tried this exact code earlier but gave up because this DID make it go off-screen and come back, but when it came back it spazzed out (for lack of a better phrase) for 2 seconds on-screen. However, I just saw this and tried again haha. Once I moved the health reset to right BEFORE the "yield WaitForSeconds" part, it worked perfectly! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "yield RespawnWaitTime();" - otherwise the function which called it will continue to execute at the same time as the coroutine is running.

Yielding the coroutine pauses execution of the code which called it, until the coroutine is finished, at which point the original code resumes from the line following the yield statement.

HOWEVER - as you can't put yield statements inside Update() - you would need to call an intermediate function, something like the following:

```
function Update () 
{
    if(health <= 0)
    {
        Respawn ();              
    }
}

function Respawn ()
{
    yield RespawnWaitTime ();
    var position = Vector3(Random.Range(-6,6),Random.Range(-4.5,4.5),0);
    transform.position = position;
    health = 2;
}

function RespawnWaitTime () : IEnumerator
{
    var offScreen = Vector3(10,10,0);
    transform.position = offScreen;
    yield WaitForSeconds(2);
}
```

Note I have also added ":IEnumerator" to RespawnWaitTime() - if you don't, the console will print an error for the yield statement that calls it. As I understand, the code will probably work despite the compile error being shown, but I prefer not to take chances ;-)